# Term for people not in any way involved in a crime/incident

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a word that refers to the people (general population) who were not involved in an incident. To be particular let's say the incident is a "crime".

That is, one you take away the perpetrators, the victims, the witnesses, lawyers, judges, cops, etc. you're left with the greater part of the population that has nothing to do with the incident or the surrounding proceedings.

Is there a term for this group?

*Something similar to, but not quite "party", as in "party to the crime", as that wouldn't include the people who are part of the proceedings.*

Comment: "The rest of us."

Comment: perhaps "uninvolved parties", "uninvolved" "unrelated" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nonparticipant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonparticipant)

Comment: I think non-participant probably comes the closest to what I mean.  Given the answers I'll assume there is no more specific, or precise, term.

Comment: "uninvolved parties" from the comments is also a very good choice.

Answer (score 17):

If they were within the general area of the crime but otherwise uninvolved, the correct word is "bystanders".

Comment: I'm considering them like witnesses, in-so-far as I want to exclude them as well. But this is the term that initially got me thinking there might be term for the group I mean.

Comment: There was a novel about kids attending [Crispus Attucks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crispus_attucks) High School, which they called "Innocent Bystander High".

Answer (score 2):

If you exclude so much from the applicable group, and when you consider bystanders being witnesses, then you might mean to be the group unaware of the whole event:

"Unawares".

Comment: It'd be kind of odd to use this word as a noun though.

Answer (score 0):

Onlookers? Spectators? Nonparticipants?

Comment: Spectators to a crime. We've pretty much gotten to that point, haven't we?